# BigCommerce bulk update categories with bigcommerce.php api

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I am pretty new to BigCommerce API programming, so this might sound weird.

I am trying to bulk update the meta information for the categories in my BigCommerce store via API. The bigcommerce.php API is my weapon of choice. I am running the php scripts locally on my Mac (MAMP).

My problem is, that the API only updates the first line (category) in the file. All others are not being touched.

Here my code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://www.******.com/',
    'username' => 'PHP_api',
    'api_key' => '**************************'
));

$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('subcats_meta_update.csv'));

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $category = array('page_title' => trim($row[1]), 'meta_keywords' => trim($row[2]),'meta_description' => trim($row[3]),'search_keywords' => trim($row[2]));
    echo Bigcommerce::updateCategory($row[0], $category);
}
```

For testing the .csv file only contains two lines with the category id in the first column and the meta information in the next 3 columns.

The foreach loop parses the file correctly. I tested this by using print_r($category) instead of running Bigcommerce::updateCategory().

I even hard-coded the array result like so (to test Bigcommerce::updateCategory()):

```
$category = array('page_title' => 'Title one', 'meta_keywords' => 'keywords one','meta_description' => 'meta descr one','search_keywords' => 'search keyw one');
echo Bigcommerce::updateCategory(1, $category);
$category = array('page_title' => 'Title two', 'meta_keywords' => 'keywords two','meta_description' => 'meta descr two','search_keywords' => 'search keyw two');
echo Bigcommerce::updateCategory(2, $category);
```

Here also, only the first update call came through.

Any idea to properly bulk update the category info?
Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct as far as I can tell. It could be there's an issue with your data?

By default the Bigcommerce API doesn't fail on error, so you might want to turn that feature on: `Bigcommerce::failOnError()`, or use `Bigcommerce::getLastError()` to see if there is an error message to work from, something like:

```
$result = Bigcommerce::updateCategory($id, $data);
if(!$result) {
    echo Bigcommerce::getLastError();
}
```